# How to calculate AIC in python?

Tags: python, log-likelihood

I have a very long time-CO2 concentration data and I fitted exponential and rectangular hyperbolic function to it with the following codes.

```
def ExponentialModel(x,a,b,c):
   cmod = a+b*np.exp(c*x)
   return cmod

def RectHypSatModel(cobs, cmax, alpha):
   cmod = (cmax*alpha*cobs)/(cmax+alpha*cobs)
   return cmod
```

They both fitted perfectly and now I need to decide which one is the best. How can I calculate AIC and BIC values for that.